# Type annotation for specific Enum value

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, type-hinting, python-typing

Is there a way in Python to get a type annotation for a specific enum value (rather than the whole enum)? For example, the following code tries to use a type annotation for `Binary.One`, which would be a subtype of `Binary`:

```
from enum import Enum, auto
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

class Binary(Enum):
    One = auto()
    Two = auto()

B = TypeVar('B', bound=Binary)

class Foo(Generic[B]):
    pass

F = TypeVar('F', bound=Foo[Binary.One])
```

However, it raises the following warning:

```
Expected type 'Optional[type]', got 'Binary' instead
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using type variables wrong.

`B = TypeVar('B', bound=Binary)` is a type variable restricted to Binary and its subtypes, not to instances of Binary. (It's a *type* variable, after all, and `Binary.One` isn't a type.) You can't create subclasses of `Binary`, so there aren't a lot of things `B` can be. It's basically restricted to `Binary` and to static type stuff that isn't a "real" type at runtime, like `Any` or literal types.

`typing` does not currently provide a way to create generic classes with enum values as parameters. It *is* possible to use a type `typing.Literal[Binary.One]`, which is a type whose sole instance is `Binary.One`, and then use that as a type parameter:

```
Foo[Literal[Binary.One]]
```

Comment: @StephaneBersier: You did explicitly call `Binary.One` a subtype of `Binary`. I figured I should address that in the answer. The first part of the answer was intended as clarification, not condescension.

Comment: I wrote "which would be a subtype of". I intentionally used the conditional mood. And, even if the relationship cannot be expressed in Python, the type that contains only `Binary.One` is nevertheless a subtype of `Binary`. Regardless, thank you for giving me a way to express this type.