# Using Enum values as type variables, without using Literal

Tags: python, inheritance, enums, type-hinting

I'm trying to represent [physical dimensions](http://www-ksl.stanford.edu/knowledge-sharing/ontologies/html/physical-quantities/PHYSICAL-DIMENSION.html) (length, time, temperature, ...), and cannot find a nice way to do so, that is compatible with type hinting and generics.

Ideally, I want to be able to define an Enum whose names are types themselves (a metaenum ?):

```
from enum import Enum

class Dim(Enum):
    TIME = "t"
    MASS = "m"
```

I can type hint dimensions (`dim: Dim`) but cannot do things like

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Dim)  # only accepts `Dim`

class PhysicalQuantity(Generic[T]):
    pass

class Container:
    some_time: PhysicalQuantity[Dim.TIME]  # doesn't work
```

[because these are values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63332993/type-annotation-for-specific-enum-value).

**Is there a construct as simple as Enum, but to make types instead of values ?**

Reasons why I want to keep `Enum`:

- very easy to define
- very easy to associate to a value (str)
- Ability to sort of "think of `Dim` as the type, and `Dim.TIME` as a subtype"

---

There are functional solutions, however I'm asking this to get a "best way" more than a "working way".
Here's what I found:

1. The simplest solution is to do use `Literal`: `SomeGenericType[Literal[Dim.TIME]]`, but this is both annoying to write each time and counter-intuitive for people who expect Dim.TIME to behave as a type.
2. Switching to classes, the most intuitive idea:

   ```
   class Dimension: 
       pass

   class TIME(Dimension): 
       pass
   ```

   doesn't work, because I want `type(TIME)` to be `Dim`, to reproduce Enum behavior
3. That leads to using a metaclass:

   ```
   class Dimension(type):
       # ... complete __init__ and __new__ to get TIME.symbol = "t"

   class TIME(metaclass=Dimension, symbol="t"): 
       pass
   ```

   This works, but I lose the ability to do `Dim.TIME`, to get `Dim.TIME` from `Dim('t')`, ...

Comment: "Ability to sort of "think of Dim as the type, and Dim.TIME as a subtype" but that's not right.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know, that's why I quoted it. If I had no typing constraints, the way I would do it is to put everything in a `dim.py` file, and have users `import dim; dim.TIME`. What I thought would be great (and initially thought Enums would offer) is the ability to add types on top, as described in the question, without having both `Dim` (the type) and `dim` (the module). Maybe it's too silly, but enums made it sound possible; and inheritance doesn't sounds like the right tool at all.

Comment: What if you made an enum with classes as the values?  (I haven’t tried this but don’t see why it wouldn’t work.)

Comment: @Samwise Thank you for the suggestion, I just tried and it doesn't change anything from using strings as values. I'm not sure why, but when using generics for example, in `SomeGeneric[Dim.TIME]` mypy will complain that it should be wrapped with `Literal` (I don't have this behaviour if I do `some_alias = TIME; SomeGeneric[some_alias]`, I'm not sure I understand enums very well).

Comment: The actual type will be the `value` property of the enum member.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem with the metaclass approach is. Can you elaborate? It seems to fit perfectly in terms of semantics. `Time` is decidedly **not** a subtype, but an _instance_ of `Dim` after all. What do you mean, you _"lose the ability to do `Dim.Time`"_? Why would you need to do that? Can't you just use `Time` directly?

Comment: If anything, it seems to me that `Quantity` should not be generic at all, but a base class for specific instances like `Time` to inherit from. (You can add that keyword-argument `symbol` magic still.) Then **`Container`** is what could be generic in terms of the _type_ of quantity (i.e. the _dimension_ of quantity) it holds. Unless I am completely missing the point here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a construct as simple as Enum, but to make types instead of values?

Yes, the metaclass. A metaclass makes types. It is simple in terms of usage i.e. creation of new types, but you do need to put in some more work to set it up properly.

Semantically, you could think of the `Dimension` is a type and `Time`, `Distance` etc. as instances of it. In other words the *type* of the `Time` class is `Dimension`. This seems to reflect your view since you said:

> I want `type(Time)` to be `Dim`

Now a `Quantity` could be considered the abstract base class of type `Dimension`. Something without a symbol.

`Time` would inherit from `Quantity` (thus also being of type `Dimension`). No generics so needed so far.

Now you can define a `Container` that is **generic** in terms of the type(s) of quantity (i.e. instances of `Dimension`) it holds.

The metaclass and base class could look like this:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Any, ClassVar, TypeVar, overload

T = TypeVar("T", bound=type)


class Dimension(type):
    _types_registered: ClassVar[dict[str, Dimension]] = {}

    @overload
    def __new__(mcs, o: object, /) -> Dimension: ...

    @overload
    def __new__(
        mcs: type[T],
        name: str,
        bases: tuple[type, ...],
        namespace: dict[str, Any],
        /,
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> T: ...

    def __new__(
        mcs,
        name: Any,
        bases: Any = None,
        namespace: Any = None,
        /,
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> type:
        if bases is None and namespace is None:
            return mcs._types_registered[name]
        symbol = kwargs.pop("symbol", None)
        dim = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
        if symbol is not None:
            mcs._types_registered[symbol] = dim
        return dim


class Quantity(metaclass=Dimension):  # abstract base (no symbol)
    pass
```

And to create new `Dimension` classes you just inherit from `Quantity`:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, reveal_type

# ... import Quantity


class Time(Quantity, symbol="t"):
    pass


DimTime = Dimension("t")
print(DimTime)        # <class '__main__.Time'>
print(type(Time))     # <class '__main__.Dimension'>
reveal_type(DimTime)  # mypy note: Revealed type is "Dimension"


Q = TypeVar("Q", bound=Quantity)


class Container(Generic[Q]):
    """generic container for `Dimension` instances (i.e. quantities)"""
    some_quantity: Q
```

I realize this completely bypasses your Enum question, but since you even phrased the question as an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) yourself by explaining what your *actual* intent was, I thought I'd give it a go and suggest a different approach.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the best way to do it. And indeed I didn't want to only expose Y because I realized there was probably no way to make "type enums" but still wanted to check, so thank you for solving X :)